# How to hide the collapsible element using js when one is clicked

Tags: javascript

I have used w3school collapsible example in my project.I am new in java script. My project works fine,but when i clicked one section,then the others does not close.How it will be closed if i click  one and other  collapsible window will be closed.I need to modify this function,but i can't use another bootstrap example as i have some limitation.I also need to add an image on the left side,and it will be changed when it will be clicked.

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 2</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 3</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this should do the work.

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");

for (var i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    // before opening the accordion, you close everything
    for (var j = 0; j < coll.length; j++) {
      coll[j].classList.remove("active");
      coll[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
    }
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

Comment: If i do that, then it will just open all and second time when i want to close them by clicking any section, it does not close. But it needs to be closed when i second time click on any section.